# html5 jcanvas click function using in "for" loop got wrong

Tags: html, canvas, jcanvas

I use the jcanvas plugin for my 2d tagcloud research. 
I wish that I could paint several tags on canvas and each of them links to a different page.
So, I need a for loop to show the tags, 
Here is my code.

```
 for(i=1;i<=5;i++){

    $("canvas").drawText({
      layer: true,
      fillStyle: "#9cf",
      strokeStyle: "#000",
      strokeWidth: 1,
      x: 100, y: 30*i,
      text: "tag"+i,
      font: "20pt 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif",

      // Event bindings
      mouseover: function() {
        $("canvas").css({cursor: "pointer"});
      },
      mouseout: function() {
        $("canvas").css({cursor: "default"});
      },
      // Click link to open it
      click: function(layer) {
        window.open("http://www.google.com/?"+i);
      }
    });
 }
```

But it turns out every tags links to the same url, that is not the result I expect.
Anyone here could help me ! thx a lot !!!

you can test it in [here](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/sandbox.php#for%28i=1;i%3C=5;i++%29%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%24%28%22canvas%22%29.drawText%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20layer%3a%20true,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fillStyle%3a%20%22#9cf%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20strokeStyle%3a%20%22#000%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20strokeWidth%3a%201,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20x%3a%20100,%20y%3a%2030%2ai,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3a%20%22tag%22+i,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20font%3a%20%2220pt%20%27Trebuchet%20MS%27,%20sans-serif%22,%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Event%20bindings%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20mouseover%3a%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28%22canvas%22%29.css%28%7Bcursor%3a%20%22pointer%22%7D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20mouseout%3a%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28%22canvas%22%29.css%28%7Bcursor%3a%20%22default%22%7D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Click%20link%20to%20open%20it%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20click%3a%20function%28layer%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.open%28%22http://www.google.com/?%22%2bi%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29;%0A%20%7D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add property id (or any other name) and change function.
`...`
`font: "20pt 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif",`
`id: i,`
`...`
`click: function(data) {`
`window.open("http://www.google.com/?"+data.id);`
`}`